# Request forwarded to new instances without completion of Startup script (AutoScalling)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, autoscaling, multiple-instances

I am using google cloud load balancer to Auto scale instances in GCP.
I have setup a Instance group of max 6 instances. When a instance is created, it runs a startup script (To install nginx, php, mongo, psql, composer, clone project).

Google Cloud load balancer forwards request to new instances firing up before the completion of automation script.

Is there a way to forward the request only after the Startup script has completed ?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I can think of in this situation is the **cool down period**. According to [this document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-cpu-load-balancing#enable_autoscaling_based_on_load_balancing_serving_capacity),

> The cool down period is the number of seconds the autoscaler should
>   wait after a virtual machine has started before the autoscaler starts
>   collecting information from it.

[image: Editing instance group for Cool-down period]

However, it will be required to find out what value to put in this field which will give enough time for the new instances to fire up completely.